# How do I disable Outlook from restricting you from sending mail if your mailbox is full

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After a storm yesterday I found myself unable to send important information to my employees because my mailbox was full. Having only access via my phone it was a problem to first clean my mailbox so I could send mail.

Sure there are ways to prevent this situation, but why is Outlook making the decision for me that I can't send mail because my mailbox is full? Is this something that can be configured in Outlook?

I'm not talking about increasing mailbox size or copying mail to a PST file, I'm talking about the unnecessary restriction of sending mail if your mailbox is full. Need to turn that off, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such restriction in Outlook.

My guess is that you are using Microsoft Exchange as the server, or a similar mail server that has restrictions upon reaching a certain quota.

All you can do is ask your administrator or email provider to lift this limit.

Comment: Well that's sorta my question, is the limit the problem or is it a configuration option that can be turned off. I know enough how mail works to know that there's no technical reason why mail can't be sent because of mailbox size. So this must be a restriction of exchange as you say. I realize either way only the sysadmin can do anything about it, but I was wondering if it's just a hardcoded thing or if it's a configurable item. Thanks.

Comment: It would be something that they set on your account - nothing is "hard coded", but, if it is controlled by group or similar, it may be a bit awkward to give you more space - but, shouldn't be too hard.